# can i merge an ethereum address, ipfs hash and a random int 32 to a single uint256 variable and convert it back to the original input

Tags: javascript, reference, solidity

I would like if somebody can provide some example implementation of the same in solidity. Or please let me know the reason how it is possible if possible at all or how it is impossible if it is impossible at all.
Thank you in advance.

I have been working with ChatGPT for the same and it gave me some functions like this,

```
    function convertAddressAndIpfsAndUniqueVector(address _addr, string memory _ipfsHash, uint32 _random) public view returns (uint256) {
        bytes memory ipfsBytes = hexStringToBytes(_ipfsHash);
        bytes memory addrBytes = abi.encodePacked(_addr);
        bytes memory combinedBytes = new bytes(ipfsBytes.length + addrBytes.length + 4);
        uint i;
        for (i = 0; i < ipfsBytes.length; i++) {
            combinedBytes[i] = ipfsBytes[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < addrBytes.length; i++) {
            combinedBytes[ipfsBytes.length + i] = addrBytes[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            combinedBytes[ipfsBytes.length + addrBytes.length + i] = bytes1(uint8(_random / (2**(8*(3-i)))));
        }
        return uint256(keccak256(combinedBytes));
    }

    function convertUint256ToAddressIpfsAndUniqueVector(uint256 _combined) public view returns (address, string memory, uint32) {
        bytes32 combinedBytes32 = bytes32(_combined);
        uint32 random = uint32(uint8(combinedBytes32[31])) * (2**24) + uint32(uint8(combinedBytes32[30])) * (2**16) + uint32(uint8(combinedBytes32[29])) * (2**8) + uint32(uint8(combinedBytes32[28]));
        bytes memory combinedBytes = new bytes(28);
        for (uint i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            combinedBytes[i] = combinedBytes32[i];
        }
        string memory ipfsHash = bytesToHexString(combinedBytes);
        address addr;
        assembly {
            addr := mload(add(combinedBytes, 0x20))
        }
        return (addr, ipfsHash, random);
    }
```

According to me the keccak256 destroys the recoverability of the inputs. Please let me know your thoughts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i merge an ethereum address, ipfs hash and a random int 32 to a single uint256 variable and convert it back to the original input

Generally not possible. Their combined size is over 256 bits, so you'd need to remove some parts in order to fit it all into one 256 bit value. And then you won't know which values to add back in order to restore the original data.

The snippet that you shared uses `keccak256` hash, which is a one-way function. You can hash the input data, but it's not possible to unshash it - to retrieve the original data back from the hash.

Edge case: If there are repeating patterns in the input data, you could compress them similarly to what ZIP and other compression algorithms are doing. But in most cases, this is not possible because the repeating patterns do not happen that often / are not large enough.